# javascript event Listener change color by each input, colorpicker

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want each div background color to be changed by each different color input of color picker.
if I choose red in input 1, I want div right below of that input tag's background color to be red
and if I choose blue in input 2, I want div right below of that input tag's background color to be blue.
Right now, it's changing both of divs.
codes are below

```js
var colorSelector;
var defaultColor = "#0000ff";
/**when page loads**/
window.addEventListener("load", startup, false);


function startup() {

  var content_color1 = document.querySelector("#content_color1");
  var content_color2 = document.querySelector("#content_color2");
  /**select input for variable **/
  colorSelector = document.querySelectorAll(".base");
  var i = 0;
  while (i < colorSelector.length) {
    /**default input*/
    colorSelector[i].value = defaultColor;

    colorSelector[i].addEventListener("change", update, false);
    i = i + 1;
  }
}

function update(event) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < colorSelector.length) {
    if (colorSelector[0].selected = true) {
      content_color1.style.backgroundColor = event.target.value;
    };
    if (colorSelector[1].selected = true) {
      content_color2.style.backgroundColor = event.target.value;
    };
    i = i + 1;

  }
}
```

```html
<input type="color" class="base ct1">
<div id="content_color1">
  cc1
</div>


<input type="color" class="base ct2">
<div id="content_color2">
  cc2
</div>
```

Comment: Please may you format the code?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to tie the color picker to its "content" dive by way of a `data-*` attribute:

```
<input type="color" class="base ct1" data-content="#content_color1">
<div id="content_color1">
  cc1
</div>
```

Then, on `update` use this to find the element and update it as needed:

```
function update(event) {
  var content = document.querySelector(event.target.dataset.content)
  content.style.backgroundColor = event.target.value;
}
```

Live example:

```js
var colorSelector;
var defaultColor = "#0000ff";
/**when page loads**/
window.addEventListener("load", startup, false);


function startup() {
  /**select input for variable **/
  colorSelector = document.querySelectorAll(".base");
  var i = 0;
  while (i < colorSelector.length) {
    /**default input*/
    colorSelector[i].value = defaultColor;

    colorSelector[i].addEventListener("change", update, false);
    i = i + 1;
  }
}

function update(event) {
  var content = document.querySelector(event.target.dataset.content)
  content.style.backgroundColor = event.target.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" class="base ct1" data-content="#content_color1">
<div id="content_color1">
  cc1
</div>


<input type="color" class="base ct2" data-content="#content_color2">
<div id="content_color2">
  cc2
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't quite understand this. How does var content = document.querySelector(event.target.dataset.content) is connected to data-content="#content_color1"  and <div id="content_color1">?  Like how can it be allowed putting id name to that data-content?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this help

```js
        var colorSelector = document.querySelectorAll('.base');
        var div1 = document.getElementById('content_color1');
        var div2 = document.getElementById('content_color2');

        var divs = [div1, div2];

        for(let i = 0; i < colorSelector.length; i++){
            colorSelector[i].addEventListener('change',() => {
                divs[i].style.backgroundColor = colorSelector[i].value;
            });
        }
```

```html
    <input type="color" class="base ct1">
    <div id="content_color1">
      cc1
    </div>


    <input type="color" class="base ct2">
    <div id="content_color2">
      cc2
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you! This was what I was looking for.